# Finding limit of $\prod_{t=1}^{n}{\left(1-\frac{2}{(n)(n+1)}\right)^2}$

Tags: limits, infinite-product

Let

$$x_n=\left(1-\frac{1}{3}\right)^2\cdot\left(1-\frac{1}{6}\right)^2\cdot\left(1-\frac{1}{10}\right)^2\cdot\left(1-\frac{1}{15}\right)^2\cdots\left(1-\frac{1}{\frac{n(n+1)}{2}}\right)^2  \quad    ,n\geq2                   $$

then $\lim_ {n\to\infty} x_n$ is

**(1)**  $\frac{1}{3}$

**(2)**  $\frac{1}{9}$

**(3)**  $\frac{1}{81}$

**(4)**  0

Comment: Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

Your method is wrong: the series

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty  \frac{2}{n(n+1)} = 2\not\to +\infty,$$
therefore you can't conclude that $\ln x_n\to 0$.

Comment: yes i notice that.thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

One can simplify $\left(1-\frac{1}{\frac{n(n+1)}{2}}\right)^2=(1-\frac{2}{n+1}+\frac{2}{n})^2=(1-\frac{2}{n+1}+\frac{2}{n})(1+\frac{2}{n+1}-\frac{2}{n})$  and then you get a lot of cancellations in the product.

Answer (score 0):

$(1-\frac{1}{\frac{n(n+1)}{2}})^2 =\frac{(n-1)(n+2)}{n(n+1)}$ which when mulitiplying causes to cancellation and will get a simple ratio,then apply limit

Comment: yes your method is right.but answer is $\frac{1}{9}$ perhaps you have not noticed square of terms.Thanks for help

Comment: yeah,right,didn't notice that :-)